# Issues while geocoding Brazilan addresses with Google API on version 4.7

Tags: wordpress, geocoding

Geocoding is not working for my addresses, I tried everything I could find on the web.

We are using the CiviCRM version 4.7 with Wordpress 4.9.4. We are adding contacts mainly using the REST API.

I have Google geocoding setup with an valid and tested API Key.

My current address format is the default one, but my **parsing is disabled**.

```
{contact.address_name}
{contact.street_address}
{contact.supplemental_address_1}
{contact.supplemental_address_2}
{contact.supplemental_address_3}
{contact.city}{, }{contact.state_province}{ }{contact.postal_code}
{contact.country}
```

When I run the scheduled job, it just says that it processed hundreds of contacts, but none of them was geocoded, displaying no errors at all.

Job params:

```
geocoding=1
parse=0
start=0
end=500
throttle=0
```

*I have also tried with throttling.*

Job Log:

```
Summary
Finished execution of Geocode and Parse Addresses with result: Sucesso (Endereços Avaliados: 483 Endereços Geodificados: 0 )
Details
Parameters raw (from db settings): 
geocoding=1
parse=0
start=0
end=500
throttle=0

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:6:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:9:"geocoding";s:1:"1";s:5:"parse";s:1:"0";s:5:"start";s:1:"0";s:3:"end";s:3:"500";s:8:"throttle";s:1:"0";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Geocode and Parse Addresses with result: Sucesso 
(Endereços Avaliados: 483
Endereços Geodificados: 0)
```

Also, when I add a new contact.. even if it has a valid address, it also doesn't work.

Can someone help me? I am really confused.

OBS: I have tried the OSM extension, but only 7 of 500 addresses were geocoded.

Comment: If you add or save a single address, does geocoding work?  The scheduled job "batch" geocoding is more complex than single address geocoding, so it might be helpful to try the single address first.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Greetings Jon!

It doesn't geocode single addresses also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue!

It seems that Google API does not support restricting DNS in server geocoding mode, I have created a new API key with IP restriction.

Beware people, it can cause you headaches.